# Transaction response doesn't contain "receipt" value

Tags: web3js, transactions, ganache, receipts, byzantium

i'm doing this send function

```
let result = await myContract.methods.myMethod().send({from: account});
console.log("result:", result);
```

using web3.js ^1.2.2 on testRPC with Ganache, hardfork Byzantium, solc compiler version 0.5.2

I expected to see in the result object the new object "receipt" with the "status" attribute, instead i receive this object:

```
{
  transactionHash: '0x13491851ee14dddab1be3112cd9ed01a4829d69b1ca304085acd165ec35ba80f',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0x4de0f8b5e1a47e630f417d6c2d5ca6af5bac2010313c76cb8ebd8752f425fb05',      
  blockNumber: 20,
  from: '0x9f93725aaff6f60d507ae6b2636bcd222eb8e19a',
  to: '0xe3f2c9598a82200e187bf927ecc9a7ed8b0dae55',
  gasUsed: 48769,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 48769,
  contractAddress: null,
  status: true,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0xdfd2b3195e7df3790d3acfbc15787f38ddeacb15de857e36a8d1c71328c6f616',
  s: '0x35bb958464b4e21f539f8aa11dc509d49dee04da0be758ae8762922f79e6b5f5',
  events: {}
}
```

unfortunately i have a constraint to read result.receipt.status, so i need the object made in that way.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of ganache are you using? What command line do you use to launch ganache? From the output it appears you are printing the receipt, since it has gasUsed, events and status. Can you try with latest version of web3.js 1.2.6?

Answer (score 0):

This IS the receipt.

---

**In web3.js v0.x, you get an object:**

```
{
    tx: ...
    receipt: {
        ...
        status: ...
        ...
    }
}
```

So you use `result.receipt.status` in order to get the status.

---

**In web3.js v1.x, you get an object:**

```
{
    ...
    status: ...
    ...
}
```

So you use `result.status` in order to get the status.

Comment: i just tried with web3.js v0.x but instead of he result object expected, it only returns the tx hash

Comment: @spawn85: Either `await` for the receipt (i.e., resolve the promise), or catch it via the `.on('receipt')` callback.

Comment: already tried of course with `await` but got just tx hash, also tried `.on('receipt')` but doesn't seem to be supported on web3.js v0.x . i was able to get the same object using `await this.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` but is not what i'm looking for

Comment: @spawn85: You'll need to better explain what exactly prevents you from replacing `result.receipt.status` with `result.status`.